# paper-drawer-toggle is not working with the paper-menu

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I'm new to Polymer. I have a paper-header-panel in that drawer i have add a paper-menu and paper-submenu elements everything is working properly but whenever i click on paper-item content i have to close drawer automatically after placing paper-drawer-toggle its doesn't work?(please find the code below)

In that code click on the 'Main' option drawer automatically hides. For remaining options the paper-drawer-toggle doesn't working.

Can anyone help me to solve these issue

Thank You

```
<a paper-drawer-toggle>Main</a>
<paper-menu attr-for-item-title="label" class="side-nav" multi>                                       
   <a paper-drawer-toggle>Home</a>
   <paper-submenu label="paper-menu">                        
       <paper-item class="menu-trigger">Reports</paper-item>
       <paper-menu class="menu-content sublist side-nav" multi>                            
            <a href="profit.html"><paper-item>Profit</paper-item></a>
            <a href="high.html"><paper-item>High</paper-item></a>
       </paper-menu>
   </paper-submenu>
</paper-menu>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting the drawer to close automatically upon clicking inside the drawer. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes but its is not happening in the paper-menu tag? can u please help me to resolve these issue @tony19